# What are some good online solvers of huge systems of non-linear equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I'm wondering cause I want to solve a non-linear system of 8 equations. https://quickmath.com/ worked for 6 equations, but for 8 it says "internal error". Can anyone help? This is quite urgent. I want all of the solutions. Thanks!$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
s+w=0
\\t+ws+x=s
\\wv+ty+sz+ux=0
\\wu+v+tx+sy+z=t
\\tz+uy+vx=u
\\uz+vy=0
\\vz=v
\\wt+u+sx+y=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: Do you need them solved numerically or exactly?

Comment: I would prefer that they are solved exactly. The numbers I want aren't extremely large(the magnitude of them are all less than 3)

Comment: Please post the system of equations you are trying to solve, because the answer heavily depends on the particular form of the equations. In any case, I would suggest using some heavy tools, like Mathematica (or its free online version, Wolfram Cloud)

Comment: Sure! Wait a minute please

Comment: Done! FYI, I would like to get all possible solutions, not just one.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question,  but wt=w*t

Comment: From the second to last equation, don't you have $z = 1$?

Comment: @Moo, good catch, or $v=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a full answer, but Wolfram Cloud solves this system and obtains 45 solutions. It refuses to display them all though.

[image]

You can sign up and check out yourself.

Though I wonder where and why would you need all 45 solutions.

Comment: Do I need to pay money?

Comment: @Chesslover, no, it's free. It might not display the full solution though, you'd need Mathematica for that, which is not free

Comment: Hmmm when I use it it keeps saying it doesn't understand my query

Comment: @Chesslover, Not Wolfram Alpha, Wolfram Cloud

Comment: @Chesslover, in any case, are you sure you need all the solutions? If the system comes, for example, from an optimization problem, you'll just need to use some algorithm for nonlinear optimization. Which, I believe, is also supported by Wolfram Cloud

Answer (score 0):

For rather large and complicated systems of equations, Excel may suit your purposes.

As it would turn out, there is a [solver plugin in Excel](https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/solver.html) which allows one to attempt to optimize systems of inequalities. For linear systems, the Simplex LP method is recommended. For smooth problems, the GRG Nonlinear method is recommended (which is your case). If it's really bad you can try the evolutionary solver, but this is usually not recommendable.

To solve systems of *equations*, you can attempt to approximate them by rewriting an equation such as $t+ws+x=s$ into $e_1=(t+ws+x-s)^2$ as the error squared. You can then set the objective function to be the sum of all of these errors.

To get multiple solutions, you can save each set of solutions and then add in the constraint $\sum_x(x-\bar x)^2\ge\epsilon$ for each variable $x$ and the previous solution $\bar x$ and some desired $\epsilon$. This can be repeated for each set of solutions until the objective function (i.e. the errors) are larger than you'd like.